# kafkajs offset management, how to get single message. I looked for solutions everywhere, but nothing seemed to work. Can anybody help me out

Tags: node.js, typescript, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I tried all the auto commit options available on kafkajs documentation, [here](https://kafka.js.org/docs/1.11.0/consuming) and also manual commits on the same. But nothing seemed to work out for me.
Is there any option that I may be missing excpet those provided in the documentation: https://kafka.js.org/docs/1.11.0/consuming

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by changing settings while instantiating the Kafka Consumer group ID. So the issue was basically, I had instantiations for producer and consumer with different group id. So, when I made them to connect using same Kafka Group ID. It worked as expected.